# Shrinking the log file does not reduce size

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, dbcc, database-size, shrink

I have a database which has a **350 MB data file** (.mdf) and a **4.9 GB log file** (.ldf). The recovery model is set to `FULL`.

When I try to shrink the log file, it's not shrinking.

I know shrinking a database is not good and it should not be done. But still i am trying to do it for shrinking the log file.

When I ran

```
DBCC SQLPerf(logspace)
```

I found that the log size is **4932 MB** and Log space used is **98.76%**!

Then I tried this command

```
USE <databasename>;
DBCC loginfo;
```

Now almost all VLFs are "status 2" which means all are in use.

I tried to take a log backup and then shrink the log file. Shrinking didn't reduce the size.

I changed the recovery model to `SIMPLE` and tried shrinking again, but this also didn't help.

I checked for open transactions

```
DBCC opentran (database);
```

and found that no transaction is open now.

What is stopping me from shrinking the log file? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question.

Run the below query to get information about the log file's reuse wait:

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'DBName'
```

I got the following output:

```
log_reuse_wait_desc
-------------------
REPLICATION
```

There were some replication-related objects remaining in the database, even after removing the replication.

To remove the replication from the database, `sp_removedbreplication` can be used. But it didn't work for us as replication was not active at the time and actually replication had been removed long before.

The solution was to import the database contents to another database using the import option of SQL Server.

Comment: I had the same problem and used this to see that there was an active transaction in the db.  `log_reuse_wait_desc` gave `ACTIVE_TRANSACTION`.  As soon as the transaction completed the shrink worked just fine.

Answer (score 12):

Read [How to Shrink SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/) for an explanation how the circular nature of the log may prevent shrink after truncation. Is possible that you log's last [LSN](http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/) point into a VLF that is at the tail of the LDF. Counter intuitively you must advance the log, by generating log writes, to allow it to shrink.

Answer (score 11):

Steps for shrinking the log are going to be:

Backup transaction log through either SSMS or T-SQL and then perform a shrink.

commands for SSMS are under the tasks if you right click the database name.

```
BACKUP LOG <Databasename> TO DISK = N'<path\database_log.ldf';
GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE (<FileName>, <TargetSize>) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

You will probably have to do this multiple times.

If there is a transaction or job blocking the action, use Activity monitor to identify the process and kill it, or use the SQL Agent job activity monitor to end the job.

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907511

Comment: But problem i encountered is different.Please see my answer below

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out, thanks for the update!

Comment: Incorrect syntax - an equals sign is missing: BACKUP LOG <Databasename> TO DISK **=** N'<path\database_log.ldf';

Answer (score 2):

I have found that I have to perform 2 or 3 backups of both the database and the transaction log to get the transaction log to actually reduce in size.  I have a database that was created with Full recovery model.  Every night it performs backups of the database and the transaction log but inevitably the transaction log seems to continually grow over 2-3 weeks.  When the remaining disk space gets to 1GB I will see that the transaction log is about 30GB.  I followed the steps recommended by Microsoft and after the 4th or 5th iteration of backing up both the database and the transaction log the transaction log will finally release its extra space and shrink.  Then I go back and delete the multiple backups I have created.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. If you take backup of log properly then unused log should be truncated. The commands given in my question may help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I approve this, same happen for me just now - only after second log backup it allowed me to perform shrink

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a backup first, dependent on the backup model that is set up for the database before you can shrink the database.

You can try running this:

```
USE <databasename>
GO

BACKUP DATABASE <databasename> TO DISK '<absolute path goes here>\<databasename>.bak';
GO
```

Or you can do that from SSMS and use the graphical tools available (see here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

Once you've backed up your database you can compress it. However, shrinking the database is not a good idea since heavy index fragmentation will occour and searching for data will become slow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know how to do backup and truncate the log and  reduce log file size. But for this database i am having problem.I just ran query select log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where name = 'dbname' and found that replication is causing the problem .But i dont have replication set on it. So how to remove the repliaction from this db which is shown in log reuse wait_desc?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Replication might be set as a Job, so open up the SQL Server Agent folder, and Expand the Jobs folder, check to see if there is a replication job set up and if so turn it off by right-clicking and selecting Stop job

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005 and up then sp_removedbreplication 'DB_NAME' will remove replication. For sql server 2000 .. refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/11/17/how-to-cleanup-replication-bits.aspx

Comment: But problem i encountered is different.Please see my answer

Answer (score -10):

My work around for the Replication that is blocking shrinking log file is:

1. Set DB Recovery Model to **Simple**
2. Take DB offline
3. Create backup of log file (just in case)
4. Delete log file
5. Bring DB online

In my case it worked. After bringing DB online log was created automatically and it's size was 512kb instead of 70GB. But this is only a workaround. The root problem is not resolved. In my case we are using replication.

Comment: This is terrible advice, never delete your transaction log, all sorts of problems can come from this such as corruption